# magento2 product custom url name_sku

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-urls

How can I change my product URL to name_sku?
Example:

> baseurl.com/shirt_35458.html

also I have product url preficx that I created a module for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by loggin in to your Admin panel.

Go to: Marketing

In the "SEO & Search" select the option "URL Rewrites".

Search for the product you want. (Let's say the url is [www.yoursite.com/**product**.html](http://www.yoursite.com/**product**.html), if you put **product** in the search bar you will find it in the list easier).

Now edit and change the URL to what you want.

let me know if you need more assistance ;)

Comment: Thanks, I want to rewrite all my products I can not do it manually one by one because they are more than 35000 product. need to do it automatically and I want to new products with this structure